# Getting max record, not value with LINQ Grouping

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have seen grouping examples to get sum or other aggregate function outputs, but i am stuck in trying to get the "record" which matches a grouped criteria, i do not need a aggregate value. Let me explain my situation:

Im using LINQ to EF, I have a table, Entity_Revisions with columns Entity_Id, Entity_Revision_Number and lots of other columns. The Entity_Revision_Number is like a version of the entity. So i want a LINQ query to give me the latest version. Below is the kind of data:

```
 Entity_Id Entity_Revision_Number
 1         0
 1         1
 2         0
 3         0
 3         1
```

I need a query that returns records 1,1 2,0 and 3,1. The query i would need is kind of

```
from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
<some joins>
<some where>
group e by e.ENTITY_ID into g
select g <where max(g.entity_revision_number)>
```

Also is it possible to get the ENTITY_REVISIONs type as output and not in the form of new{} annonymous type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by id, order each group descending by revision number, and get first value of each group should be fine :

```
var query = from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
            group e by e.ENTITY_ID into grp
            select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.entity_revision_number).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
var query = 
 from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
 group e by e.ENTITY_ID into g
 select new {
   Entity_Id = g.Key,
   Entity_Revision_number = (from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
                             where e.ENTITY_ID == g.Key
                             select e.entity_revision_number).Max()
 };
```

Comment: Yup, that would work, but how do i get the complete ENTITY_REVISION object type without having to genreate a new annonymous type. It has about 20 columns, so do i build the structure by hand? Having said that, below is what i tried and it said ENTITY_NAME doesnt exist
     from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
     group e by e.ENTITY_ID into g
     select new {
       Entity_Id = g.Key,
       Entity_Name = g.ENTITY_NAME,
       Entity_Revision_number = (from e in ENTITY_REVISIONs
                             where e.ENTITY_ID == g.Key
                             select e.ENTITY_REVISION_NUMBER).Max()}